# Selecting specific fields from a table with SELECT *

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

I have two tables - I want to be able to select data from tbl1 and insert it into tbl2. Now here's the deal - Tbl1 has roughly about 30 fields. There are three columns in that table that are not in tbl2. Instead of specifying each field individually, i was trying to see if there's any possible way from me to do something like this...

```
Insert into Tbl2 SELECT * (but three fields) from tbl1 where value='value'
```

or do something like

```
Insert Into tbl2 SELECT Field1, Field2
```

but because I'll be doing this for many different tables in each case tbl1 will have 3 extra fields then the corresponding tb2 - i'm trying to do it in the simples and cleanest way possible

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why all those columns, and why moving around data?

Comment: @jarlh need to give user an option to UNDO something that they've previously done -

Comment: If you want to do it properly, specify columns!

Comment: You should ALWAYS specify your columns. If you want to save some typing you can drag the columns "folder" from SSMS to a query window and it will bring all the column names in to your query. Then just delete the three columns you don't want.

Comment: in object explorer right click source table - click `select top N rows`, delete the 3 columns you don't want, copy and paste.  done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done, there is no syntax to insert or select 'all fields except'.

And if there were it would be a bad idea to use it, for exactly the same reason that `select *` in application code is a bad idea. (Assuming the table definition(s) will never change and that you always need all the data.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this way?

Example:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, Country FROM Suppliers
WHERE Country='Germany';
```

Comment: Well yes but I already know how to do it this way trying to find a way to not specify every field

Answer (score 1):

```
 declare @sql as nvarchar(2000)
 declare @columns as nvarchar(1000) = ''
 select @columns = @columns + '[' + c.name + '], ' 
 from syscolumns c join sysobjects o on c.id=o.id 
 where o.name = 'tbl1' and c.name not in ('col1name', 'col2name', 
 'col3name')
 set @columns = left(@columns,len(@columns)-2)
 set @sql = N'Insert Into tbl2 (' + @columns + ') values (' + @columns + ')'
 exec(@sql)
```

where col1name..col3name are the columns you want to miss out

Comment: thanks - I'm not trying to get too crazy - I'm just specifying all the fields and leaving it for now as is. !